# Script bundles not rendering individual files in debug

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have two script bundles defined:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/common").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"));

bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/scripts/sectionCommon").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/A.js",
                        "~/Scripts/B.js",
                        "~/Scripts/C.js"));
```

I have one set on my master layout page:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/common")
```

And one set on a subset of my pages where it is used:

```
@Scripts.Render("Scripts/sectionCommon")
```

So far so good and this works.

When I run my site using debug compilation, the JS files from the first bundle are rendered to the markup as individual script links per file, whereas the second bundle remains as a single minified bundle:

```
<script src="/siteRoot/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script src="/siteRoot/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/siteRoot/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script src="/siteRoot/Scripts/sectionCommon"></script>
```

Does anybody have any idea why this might be happening?  Bit of a pain while debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured this out while I was writing the question.  Thought I would answer it in case this bites anybody else.  The difference between the two was using the tilda to get a site relative url:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/scripts/common")

@Scripts.Render("Scripts/sectionCommon")
```

Both of these render out the script as intended, but only the top one (using the site relative URL) was rendering out the individual script references in debug.