# Debugging bundled and versioned javascript files

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I've used Bundleconfig.cs to bundle my javascript files as follows:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/resultscripts").Include(
             "~/Scripts/spectrum.js",
              "~/Scripts/notify.js",
              "~/Scripts/spin.min.js"));
   BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Then in my .cshtml file, I've got the following:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/resultscripts");
```

This renders in chrome as:

```
<script src="/bundles/resultscripts?v=3ozhz2yni5K8Is0g9QoONh_MkoivcBzooVIUD-a0Ngw1"></script>
```

Then I have the following under system.web in my Web.config (not sure how much this matters):

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
```

This is good because it allows bundle versioning.  However, some of my javascript doesn't seem to be firing, and when in Chrome, I can now no longer place breakpoints in my individual javascript files.  Or to be more clear, I can't find notify.js for example.  I'm guessing this is because the bundle is being minified.

If I set `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;` my javascript files render but are no longer versioned.

I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction so that I can find the individual files when bundling with versions?

I checked out this: [Script bundles not rendering individual files in debug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26102120/script-bundles-not-rendering-individual-files-in-debug), and am using the same syntax, but my files are not getting rendered individually.

Comment: After bundling, you cannot debug the JavaScript codes easily. It is an expected behavior. What is your concern? Do you see any script error?

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly:  I should have been more clear:  My concern is that when I have BundleTable.EnableOptimizations set to true, some of my scripts aren't firing.  When I have it set to false, everything works fine.  The debugging issue is something I can live with.

Answer (score 1):

I hope below statement will be helpful  for you:

when we are not in a debug compilation and have not turned off the EnableOptimizations feature, MVC will combine those files in our bundles, compress (minify) them and output only a single script tag

**Source :** https://stackoverflow.com/a/21271866/3397630

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `.*` and see any different?

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/resultscripts").Include(
   "~/Scripts/spectrum.*",
   "~/Scripts/notify.*",
   "~/Scripts/spin.*"));

BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

Comment: Do you have spectrum.min.js and notify.min.js files?

Comment: If so, could you add them as `.Include("~/Scripts/spectrum.min.js","~/Scripts/notify.min.js","~/Scripts/spin.min.min.js"));`

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm missing something... How is that different than what I have?

Comment: If it sees *.min file, it uses *.min and bundle them. Otherwise, it becomes two steps - minify and then bundle. Sometimes, minifying could mess up the files unintentionally.

Comment: So... I have more information:  It turns out that the offending files were .css files that I had referenced in Syles.Render blocks.  When I took these out, things seemed to work fine.  Any idea of why this would be happening?

Comment: Style.Render is where a bundle is rendered to browser. Some CSS files are sensitive to resource path. For that case you cannot bundle them. *For example, Kendo UI in my sample code [Kendo](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs#L30) and [Bundle](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin/blob/master/src/Presentation/AspNetMvcActiveDirectoryOwin.Web/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml#L8).*

Comment: Thanks guys.  Stay tuned.  I'll post my solution soon.